# how do automatically distinguish between FAT-x types for a partclone backup?

Tags: partitioning, backup

I'm writing some backup scripts on Xubuntu bionic, and having trouble getting full information about some of the thumb drive types.  Most Linux utilities just report them as vfat, but partclone has three different programs for backing them up: partclone.{fat12|fat16|fat32}.  I'm new to this, so I'm not clear on the differences among them, but it sure looks like I should choose the correct one.

I'm used to parsing the output of utilities like sfdisk, blkid and lsblk but none of these seem to tell me what I need: they just call them vfat.

How can my scripts tell which partclone to use when all they know is the device path (/dev/sdg or /dev/sdg1 for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this question.  I looked a little further and found all those apparent variants of partclone link to the same executable.  So it does not matter which variant I'm working with because partclone will figure it out.